Deduction construction examples in Kleene's "Introduction to Metamathematics"
The deductions for construction proposed to readers seem to be pretty easy, but I'm not quite sure of my solution. I'm talking about the example 2 in §20.
The first one is to construct $A\&B$ from $A$ and $B$ (I will use $\Rightarrow$ instead of $\supset$ because it is less confusing).

$A$ is given.
$B$ is given.
Let's build truth table

+-------------+
| A | B | A&B |
+---+---+-----+
| T | T |  T  |
+---+---+-----+
| T | F |  F  |
+---+---+-----+
| F | T |  F  |
+---+---+-----+
| F | F |  F  |
+---+---+-----+



We've got if $A$ and $B$ is true, then $A\&B$ is also true.

The last step is to say $A\&B\Rightarrow A\&B$ is tautology.


The second one is to construct $C$ from $A\&B\Rightarrow C$, $A$, and $B$.

$A$ is given.
$B$ is given.
$A\&B ⇒ C$ is given.
Truth table:

+-----------------------+
| A | B | A&B | A&B ⇒ C |
+---+---+-----+---------+
| T | T |  T  |    T    |
+---+---+-----+---------+
...

We'll omit others, cause they violate assumptions (we could leave only one row in the first table too).

Because $A\&B$ is true then $A\&B \Rightarrow C$ true when and only when $C$ is true.

Am I right?

"The last step is to say..." NO; what uou have constructed is $A, B \vdash A & B$ i.e. a deduction of formula $A & B$ from assumptions $A$ and $B$.

Regarding the other case, not clear... There are three statements: A,B,C and you have - in principle - to build the full TT with the $2^3$ rows and then check that in ALL rows where the three assumptions $A, B, A & B \to C$ are TRUE also the conclusion $C$ is.

@MauroALLEGRANZA, you've said all rows, where three assumptions are true, so we get two rows $A=T$, $B=T$, $A&B\Rightarrow C=T$, but the first one where $C=T$ and the other one where $C=F$. The last one cannot exist, because if $C=F$ and $A&B=T$ (which is by assumptions) we'll get $T\Rightarrow F$ which is $F$ and this contradicts with our third assumption. And what about others I don't understand why I must build $2^3-1$ rows more, if any of them contradists with our assumptions without regarding $C$.

Perfect; this is the TT algorithm. Of course, we can use it with intelligence and avoid unnecessary work. Having said that, the issue stands: are you asked to build a TT or are you asked to write a derivation?

@MauroALLEGRANZA, hm, I thought we can use TT in derivation, even if it wasn't used in the book (just cause I've found paper where it was used). And if we get back to the first case, then the deduction could be something like this: 1. $A$. 2. $B$. 3. $A&B$ from 1, 2?

@MauroALLEGRANZA, and those rules are 5a and 5b, i.e. $A \Rightarrow A \vee B$ and $B \Rightarrow A \vee B$, are they not?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

So, the first one.

$A$ is given.
$B$ is given.
$A\Rightarrow(B\Rightarrow A\&B)$ by the third rule, and 1 and 2.
$\frac{A, A\Rightarrow (B\Rightarrow A\&B)}{B\Rightarrow A\&B}$ by Modus Ponens (or the second rule), 1 and 3.
$\frac{B, B\Rightarrow A\&B}{A\&B}$ by Modus Ponens, 2 and 4.
$A\&B$ by 5.

The second one is provided by @MauroALLEGRANZA.

$A$ is given
$B$ is given
$A\&B\Rightarrow C$ is given
$A\&B$ from 1 and 2 and previous Example
$C$ from 3 and 4 by Modus Ponens.


"The last step is to say..." No, what uou have constructed is $A,B⊢A \& B$  i.e. a deduction of formula $A \& B$ from assumptions $A$ and $B$
The second case is not clear: there are three statements: A,B,C and you have - in principle - to build the full truth-table with the $2^3=8$ rows and then check that in all rows where the three assumptions $A,B,A \& B → C$ are True also the conclusion $C$ is true.
Having said that, if you have to "show deductions" you have to write the sequence of formulas starting with the assumptions and applying rules (Conjunction Introduction, Modus Ponens, etc).
This means that the "deduction construction" will be: 1. $A$, 2. $B$, 3. $A \& B → C$ - given, 4. $A \& B$ - from 1. and 2. by Conjunction Introduction, and so on.
